# How to read lines of a stream in Codename One

Tags: stream, codenameone, bufferedreader

In Java standard I can read a stream, line by line, using, for instance, the readLine() method of the BufferedReader class. In the com.codename1.io package that class is not present.

How can I achieve the same goal in Codename One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for readline in our current stream code as it's not the most efficient way to read streams. I would suggest using a method such as `Util.readToString` and then parse the String which will probably be more efficient.

However, if you want to replace readLine you can do something like this (didn't test it):

```
private String readLine(Reader is) throws IOException {
   int nextChar = is.read();
   if(nextChar == -1) {
       return null;
   }
   StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
   while(nextChar > -1) {
       ret.append((char)nextChar);
       nextChar = is.read();
       if(nextChar == '\n') {
          return ret.toString();
       }
   }
   return ret.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Shai. Can you explain me how to use `Util.readToString`? Why is more efficient?

Comment: It buffers the input as a single block. Just invoke that method and you will get the full file as a String and you can then tokenize it by rows using `for(String line : StringUtil.tokenize(Util.readString(stream), '\n') {...}`